Coq: how to apply "only once"
I'm having a stupid struggle with Coq. Although, given
Goal 1

P, Q : Prop
H : P
H0 : P -> Q
(1 / 1)
False

when I apply H0 in H as H1, I get
Goal 1

P, Q : Prop
H : P
H0 : P -> Q
H1 : Q
(1 / 1)
False

the things turn out not to go as I want with a double implication: when given
Goal 1

P, Q, R : Prop
H : P
H0 : P -> Q -> R
(1 / 1)
False

when I apply H0 in H as H1 I get two goals:
Goal 1

P, Q, R : Prop
H : P
H0 : P -> Q -> R
H1 : R
(1 / 2)
False

Goal 2

P, Q, R : Prop
H : P
H0 : P -> Q -> R
(2 / 2)
Q

But I would like something like
Goal 1

P, Q, R : Prop
H : P
H0 : P -> Q -> R
H1 : Q -> R
(1 / 2)
False

Is it possible that the apply (or any other command) does so? My goals may get unprovable with what Coq does, no?

It is certainly possible. The easiest way is to
assert P as HP.
- (* proof of P here *)
- pose proof (H0 HP) as H1; clear HP.

A more hacky option is of course unshelve epose proof (H0 _) as H1. If you are not afraid of using libraries, you can use std++ and then use their opose proof (H0 _) as H1 which avoids unshelving unnecesarily many evars.

I got problems with the assert solution, but unshelve is great.

There is no need for an assert since you already have a proof of P. pose proof (H0 H) as H1 works.

Sure but assert is the most general solution here since it works in all cases.

apply does some eager reduction: you can use specialize (H0 H). here.

My goals may get unprovable with what Coq does, no?

Assuming there are no bugs/issues with the tactics: no, but, depending on the tactics used, not only getting to the bottom of the proof might get more or less complicated, also the associated proof term (you can Print it after the Qed/Defined) would correspondingly be more or less complex.
